# compare folder contents

Tags: python

I need to compare two folders on a XP machine.

This is a radio station, we have all our music stored as high bitrate mp3, when new songs are acquired from CD they are wav. I need to be able to compare the mp3 and the wav folders for duplicates (naming will be identical except for the file extension). The object is to produce a list of items in the wav folder that don't have mp3 versions.

Python 2.7 is installed and my very limited experience of coding has been with python.

All help appreciated, even if it is just a kick in the right direction...
Thanks.

Comment: Read the file names from the 2 folder, process the file name with regex or simple indexOf to remove the extension, put the file names into the set that correspond with it (we use 2 sets, each set for one folder). Then iterate through one of the sets and find whether the file name is present in the other set. I'm not using python that much, but there should be some type of set, which is internally a tree or a hash table.

Comment: @nhahtdh, +1 for posting directions instead of solution.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get the folder contents, and [`os.path.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to determine the base name:

```
import os
wavs = set(os.path.splitext(fn)[0] for fn in os.listdir('/path/to/wavs'))
mp3s = set(os.path.splitext(fn)[0] for fn in os.listdir('/path/to/mp3s'))
must_convert = wavs - mp3s
```

If you want to collate the mp3s and wavs of multiple folders (but not recursively), you'll have to store both basename and the full filename:

```
import os,collections
files = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for d in ['/path/to/wavs', '/more/wavs', '/some/mp3s', '/other/mp3s']:
    for f in os.listdir(d):
        basename,ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        files[ext][basename] = os.path.join(d, f)
files_to_convert = [fn for basename,fn in files['.wav'].items()
                       if basename not in files['.mp3']]
```

Comment: just personal curiosity: will this work even when there are nested sub-folders? I mean, will it recursively look for files in subfolders too?

Comment: @nadirs Nope (since the recursive version wouldn't be such a neat 3-liner). Do you need a recursive comparison?

Comment: @phihag No I'm not the OP, I was just curious about it. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: This works well for me. However, if the mp3 files were in more than one folder (not sub folders) how would I collate all the mp3 files before comparing them with the wavs?

Comment: @floatingshed Then it gets more complicated. Updated with a solution for that problem.

Comment: I get an error in line 6:
    files[ext][basename] = os.path.join(d, f)
TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @Floatingshed Oops, there was an error indeed, in line two. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

```
    import os
    wav=[os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in os.listdir(r'C:\Music\wav') if os.path.splitext(x)[1]=='.wav']
    mp3=[os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in os.listdir(r'C:\Music\mp3') if os.path.splitext(x)[1]=='.mp3']  

   #here wav is a list names of only those files whose extension is .wav 
   #here mp3 is a list names of only those files whose extension is .mp3 

    print(set(wav)-set(mp3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works recursively, slightly based on *phihag*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11167981/241039).

```
import os
sets = {}
for dirname in 'mp3_folder', 'wav_folder':
    sets[dirname] = set()
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
        sets[dirname].update(os.path.join(path, os.path.splitext(fn)[0]).lstrip(dirname) for fn in files)
must_convert = sets['mp3_folder']-sets['wav_folder']
print('\n'.join(sorted(must_convert)))
```